# Self-hosted сервис и работа с HTTPS

Tags: c#, ssl, https, asp, webapi

Есть self hosted приложение. Необходимо все его перевести на протокол HTTPS, сертификат SSL есть. На деплое к сервису обращаются через 80 порт.

Проблема в том что такое решение :

> add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:80
>   certhash=989a847890s82ae6d76c2dd4779eb3a13as41f08
>   appid={ba77e2bd-7499-44ee-bfb0-b45188f94e7f}

Выбивает постоянную ошибку - `The parameter is incorrect.`
Какие еще есть методы решения?

Comment: А разве не `ipport=0.0.0.0:443`? Где вы видели на 80 порту https? Смущает меня это "На деплое к сервису обращаются через 80 порт". У меня `netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=asdfasdf appid=asdf` работает вообще без проблем.

Comment: Кстати, [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/779228/5752652) пишут ещё про вариант "скрытые символы попали в текст команды", проверьте.